# Im not understanding user defined functions in python

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

Im new to python.can anyone please explain me how a,c,b is printed? I know foo executes at first and then prints a but after that I can't understand anything.

```
    def foo():
        print("a")
        bar()
        print("b")
    def bar():
        print("c")
    foo() 

    Output:
    a
    c
    b
```

Comment: Do you have a guess what is happening? What do you think should be happening?

Comment: after printing *a* the function *foo* calls *bar* whose prints *c* then return to function *foo* whose prints *b*.  Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens:

1. The first function is bound to the name `foo`.
2. The second function is bound to the name `bar`.
3. We call the function bound to `foo`:

   1. We print `"a"` to the console.
   2. We call the function bound to `bar`:

      1. We print `"c"` to the console.
      2. Reaching the end of the function, we return `None`.
   3. Nothing is done with the return value of `bar()`, so we throw it away.
   4. We print `"b"` to the console.
   5. Reaching the end of the function, we return `None`.
4. Nothing is done with the return value of `foo()`, so we throw it away.
5. We've reached the end of the script, so Python exits normally.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 seperate functions: foo() and bar()

```
def foo():
    print("a")
    bar()
    print("b")
    
def bar():
    print("c")

foo()
```

Both functions are at initialized (loaded but not executed) but not called (executed).
The foo() statement at the end will now call only the foo() function.

Ok, now lets go through the foo() function step by step.

1. it print("a") - as expected
2. it calls the bar() function. Therefore we now move to the bar() function.
   As we can see the bar() function will print("c") and ends there.
   Because of this we move back to the foo() function and continue there.
3. print("b") will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned `foo` is called first and it prints `a`. Then in the `foo` function we call `bar`, and in `bar` we print `c` then the function `bar` return to the `foo` function and it continues with printing `b`. I hope it clarifies more what’s happening.